# How to group and count record by date using Laravel?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have an **issues** table, it has a column **created_at**, and **status** which can be 'Open' or 'Closed'

I need to get the count of issues depending on the status per month.
I want to get something like this:

```
January 2018: {
  open: 300,
  closed: 28,
},
February 2018: {
  open: 250,
  closed: 80
}
```

I don't know if there's a better approach, I'm open to suggestion in how I would retrieve the data. Basically I'm creating an admin dashboard and want to display the data in a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL:

```php
$months = Issue::select(
    DB::raw("date_format(created_at, '%M %Y') month"),
    DB::raw("sum(if(status = 'Open', 1, 0)) open"),
    DB::raw("sum(if(status = 'Closed', 1, 0)) closed")
)->groupBy('month')->get();
```

You can set the key with `keyBy()`:

```php
$months = $months->keyBy('month');
```