# PHP Laravel filtering array from API

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using the Laravel Http client and getting the data from external API.
When I create schedules and post to the API, I'm getting the result like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "321322",
    "date": "2024-03-21",
    "serviceTimeRange": {
      "startHour": "10:00",
      "endHour": "12:00",
      "id": "212367",
      "service": {
        "id": "333444",
        "serviceCode": "press"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "565332",
    "date": "2024-03-21",
    "serviceTimeRange": {
      "startHour": "12:00",
      "endHour": "14:00",
      "id": "234892",
      "service": {
        "id": "333444",
        "serviceCode": "press"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "785434",
    "date": "2024-03-22",
    "serviceTimeRange": {
      "startHour": "10:00",
      "endHour": "12:00",
      "id": "993218",
      "service": {
        "id": "777888",
        "serviceCode": "conference"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see from the result, in the first and the second record, the service->id has a same id (333444).

If I loop like this:

```
@foreach($schedules as $schedule)
  <tr> 
    <td> {{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($schedule->date)) }} </td>
    <td> {{ $schedule->serviceTimeRange->service->serviceCode }} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm getting the result:

```
21-Mar-2024
press

21-Mar-2024
press

22-Mar-2024
conference
```

The question is: How can I combine the result that has same date and to be like this:

```
21-Mar-2024 
press
2 //where 2 is the count of the serviceTimeRange hours


22-Mar-2024
conference
1 //where 1 is the count of the serviceTimeRange hours
```

Comment: Subtract [end and start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php) time ?

Comment: I don't see any point of using the PHP date functions or similar (DateTime) but instead I'm searching for a different way of displaying the data I'm getting. In the array, there's the object "date", so there must be a way to filter by that object.

Comment: Seems like query builder `GroupBy('date')` functionality then or something similar.

Comment: Yes, I see. And he uses my mentioned "GroupBy" interface, just not on query builder, but on collection instance.  You should try to explore proposed solutions yourself and not only to expect full-baked answers which propagates "copy-paste programming", which is BAD in general.

Comment: I agree with you and that's why I'm reading the Laravel documentations for Collections and Database: Query Builder entirely.

Comment: This should be sufficiently inspiring: [Laravel Collection with groupby, count and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62550381/2943403) and [Laravel Eloquent groupBy() AND also return count of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18533080/2943403) and [laravel eloquent count with a groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391108/2943403) and [How to group and count record by date using Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51027510/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by grouping the schedules by date and then counting the number of `serviceTimeRange` for each date. First, convert the array of schedules to a Laravel collection.

```php
$schedules = collect($schedules);
```

Then, group the schedules by date.

```php
$grouped = $schedules->groupBy('date');
```

Now, you can loop through the grouped schedules in your view and count the number of `serviceTimeRange` for each date.

```php
@foreach($grouped as $date => $schedules)
  <tr> 
    <td> {{ date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date)) }} </td>
    <td> {{ $schedules->first()->serviceTimeRange->service->serviceCode }} </td>
    <td> {{ $schedules->count() }} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```